# Listen JList setSelectedIndex

Tags: java, swing, listener, jlist

```
MyJList myList = new MyJList();
    myList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

    if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
        System.out.println("Selected!");
    }
    }
});
```

.
.
.

```
class MyList extends JList{


    public MyList () {
    super();

    this.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 

    this.setSelectedIndex(0);

   }
```

}

When I click on list item with mouse, I see message «Selected!».

When program start, this message not shown, but item #0 is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `setSelectedIndex` in the constructor

Then after that, add the `SelectionListener`

when `setSelectedIndex` is called...there is no Listener

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what should happen. `valueChanged` is only called when the user selects the item. `setSelectedIndex` does not invoke any listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the order of you code:

a) you create the list and set the index to 0
b) you add the ListSelectionListener. Well nothing has changed since you added the listener so no event is fired.

Try adding:

```
list.setSelectedIndex(1)
```

after adding the listener to see if the event is fired.